# Пропускная способность сети

Tags: сеть

Как кадр/c перевести в мбит/с?

Comment: Видео-поток же сжат обычно.

Comment: спасибо, уже нашел ответ на свой вопрос: пропускная способность сети выщитывается как произведение частоты, размера пакета и 8 (если размер в байтах), а ответ будет в БИТАХ/С.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Число кадров в секунду перевести в мегабиты в секунду весьма непросто. Начнём с простого.

**Несжатые данные.** Предположим, что у нас есть кадр размера `X*Y` с числом бит `B` на пиксель. В этом случае на кадр уйдёт `X*Y*B` бит. Пусть теперь у нас `F` кадров в секунду. Тогда в секунду нам потребуется `X*Y*B*F` бит. Разделив на 8, получим байты в секунду, ещё на 1024 - килобайты в секунду, и ещё на 1024 - мегабайты в секунду.

**Сжатые данные.** А вот теперь сложности. Видеопоток крайне редко передаётся в несжатом виде. Даже несжатые данные часто немного оптимизируются. Например, яркостная составляющая передаётся для каждого пикселя, а цветоразностные - для групп 2x2 или 4x4 пикселя. В большинстве же случаев используется сжатие видеопотока. Сжатие бывает безпотерьное (например, алгоритм Хаффмана) или с потерями (кодировщики XviD, H.264 и т.д.). Какой поток данных необходим кодеку часто не может сказать даже сам кодек. Точные цифры зависят от количества движения в кадре, числа мелких деталей, требуемого качества картинки и т.п. Точные цифры становятся известными постфактум, после того как поток будет закодирован и могут отличаться в десятки раз.

Comment: Боюсь задача не про видео была. Имелся ввиду кадр канального уровня сети, а не на экране

Comment: @Mike Автор не умеет правильно задать вопрос или считает других телепатами. Но это не имеет значения. Вопрос всё равно удалят.